# Uploading video to linkedin using v2 API

Tags: linkedin-api

Hello I cannot manage to upload videos on linkedIn member account using V2 API

I followed the instructions described at the official page
the steps to upload a video (under 200 MB) are

1. Register an upload for Video
2. Upload the video
3. Check status of upload

they all worked , and the last step gives back a successful respose

```
  {
        "serviceRelationships": [
            {
                "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent",
                "relationshipType": "OWNER"
            }
        ],
        "recipes": [
            {
                "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image",
                "status": "AVAILABLE"
            }
        ],
        "mediaTypeFamily": "STILLIMAGE",
        "created": 1583915898789,
        "lastModified": 1583916648095,
        "id": "C4D22AQELBNtjd0NB2Q",
        "status": "ALLOWED"
    }
```

but the video is not displayed in the linked in account page..
I thought it needs to be shared as for the image,  but the ugcPosts API does not work..

is this still a closed feature by LinkedIn?
if so how can it be granted?

Any suggestion is higly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hey as stated in the documentation you can use uploaded assets with their corresponding asset urn in ugcPosts (videos) or shares (images).

What got my attention in your question you register a video upload and get back

> ```
>     "recipes": [
>         {
>             "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image",
>             "status": "AVAILABLE"
>         }
>     ],
>     "mediaTypeFamily": "STILLIMAGE",
> ```

This indicates to me that you used the wrong recipe in the registerUpload request. It should be `urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video`